# Kosher wine recommendations

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, gifts, grapes-wine

When people go away for shabbos they often bring along a gift to their hosts. What is a good Kosher wine - not too dry - that you can give for less than $20?

Answer (score 9):

At the risk of being boring, the [Bartenura Moscato ("blue bottle")](http://www.kosherwine.com/bartenura-moscato.html) is usually well-received.  [Mevushal](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/ask_the_expert/at/Ask_the_Expert_Mevushal.shtml).  Easy to find at most kosher wine places these days.

For those who prefer something Israeli, there's the [Carmel](http://www.kosherwine.com/carmel-moscato-di-carmel-2.html) analogue (yes mevushal) of the "blue bottle", and the [Gamla](http://www.royalwine.com/wines/gamla-moscato) (non-mevushal).

Comment: Appreciate all suggestions - would not mind a few more ideas.

Comment: +1 for Batenura Moscato, and they also make a nice pinot grigio if moscato is a little *too* sweet for people.

Comment: Some don't like the Hashgacha on Bartenura's wines. So caveat emptor.

Comment: @Double mai hai?

Comment: @user6591 The mashgiach is a raving messianist, so I hear. [Many believe such people cannot be trusted on Halachic matters.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27802/759) See for instance https://books.google.com/books?id=-_4eAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA55&ots=FFwDh6zsuD&dq=Rabbi%20Garelik%20wine%20chabad%20meshichist&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q=Rabbi%20Garelik%20wine%20chabad%20meshichist&f=false

Comment: @Double that's sad. Gonna have to do some research. Thanks for the heads up. I can't believe i haven't heard this before.

Answer (score 6):

If you like the idea of a decent wine (cabernet, etc.) but find them a touch too dry, try Herzog's Jeunesse (a semi-dry, usually too sweet for real dry wine drinkers).  $10-12 a bottle.

Comment: If you read the cursive wrong it may look like "Tennessee" at first ...

Answer (score 6):

I enjoy white Zinfandel. It comes in a nice pink shade, and it's got just enough sweetness to pull out of being truly dry.

Baron Herzog makes it in California, and Carmel makes it in Israel. It looks like they [can be found](http://www.google.com/products?hl=en&hs=WZp&q=%28carmel%20OR%20herzog%29%20white%20zinfandel) for under $10 and under $15, respectively.